# Javascript Game Loop - How to know how much time has passed in an function outside the loop

Tags: javascript, loops

You have to know I'm still new to this new game development in javascript.

First of all I have this game loop

```
GameLoop = {

  //Insert more members here if needed
  id : null,

  run : function(options) {

    var now,
        dt       = 0,
        //last     = timestamp(),
        last     = Date.now(),
        slow     = options.slow || 1, // slow motion scaling factor
        step     = 1 / options.fps || 60,
        slowStep = slow * step,
        update   = options.update,
        render   = options.render;


    function frame() {
        //now = timestamp();
        now = Date.now();
        dt = dt + Math.min(1, (now - last) / 1000);
        while(dt > slowStep) {
            dt = dt - slowStep;
            update(step);
        }
        render(dt / slow);
        last = now;
        this.id = requestAnimationFrame(frame, options.canvas);
    }
    this.id = requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  },

  pause : function() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);
  }

};
```

I created it using some documentation and tutorials from the internet. And what I want to know how I can have a function that changes a state variable every 1 second or every 60 frames. For example, I can have this inside my Draw methods:

```
//Moves enemy towards the player 30px every second
function moveEnemy() {
    if(one Second Has Passed Since Last Time We Moved) {
        enemy.xPosition += '30px';
    }
}
```

This is just an hypothetic example of what I want to achieve, I hope someone with experience with these game loops can help me. If you need more information, let me know, or if I need to update my question for some reason.

Thank you!

Comment: Just do `enemy.xPosition += 30 * dt; // px/s * s/frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to move the enemy once every second, no need for that to be inside the frame loop.

```
var enemyMoverInterval = setInterval(
    function moveEnemy() {
        enemy.xPosition += '30px';
    }
}, 1000);
```

EDIT: If you really want to have it in the game loop...

```
var enemyLastMoved = new Date();
GameLoop = {
    // ...
    function frame() {
        // ....
        if (now - enemyLastMoved > 1000) {
            enemy.xPosition += '30px';
            enemyLastMoved += 1000;
        }
        // ...
```

Or a hybrid approach:

```
var enemyMustMove = false;
setInterval(function() {
    enemyMustMove = true;
}, 1000);
```

and in the game loop:

```
        // .... 
        if (enemyMustMove) {
            enemyMustMove = false;
            enemy.xPosition += '30px';
        }
```

PS `enemy.xPosition += '30px'` probably does not do what you want.

Comment: But this setInterval function would be called 60 times a second, creating a new interval each loop... what do you think?

Comment: No, put it *outside* the frame loop. Only one interval, triggering once per second.

Comment: Although it could work, it would break the structure of every element from the game being processed and drown inside the UPDATE and DRAW function inside the loop

Comment: You should do `enemyLastMoved += 1000`, not `enemyLastMoved = now`.

Comment: Thanks, after some minor modifications to your answer, I got it working! thanks!